# Tool to visualize values from variables during the execution of a program in C

Tags: c, variables, stack

I just need to see what is stored, in realtime, in some particular variables and struct used by an application written in C.

I need something like the stack tracer that comes with the ADT plugins for Eclipse as part of the Android sdk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly you just need to use a debugger.  If you compiled with gcc then you can use gdb.  You will want to add the -g -O0 flags to include debugging symbols and turn off optimization.  If you need to you can even attach gdb to a running process.  I know microsoft has a similar debugger I'm just not familiar with it.

Comment: the problem is that, as you pointed out, this tools needs a series of symbols, if i can't access the source code to recompile the app, how can i solve this?

Comment: @user827992 You can't...... Without the debug information the debugger has no way to know where the source code is located, so cannot show you the source. You can still debug at the assembly level.